# Display image in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm desperately trying to populate my ListView with downloaded Graphics at runtime. So far I've tried several approaches but i couldn't get it to work properly.

The Download and display for itself (i tested in a canvas called pic, so there's still fragments in the code) works fine, but the ListView won't display the damn image.

C# code:

```
    private async void LoadFlags(RootAutomarken automarken)
            {
                Image flag = new Image();
                var client = new HttpClient();
                foreach (var item in automarken.Automarken)
                {
                    flag = await LoadFlag(item.Land, client);
                    mainList.Items.Add(new CarListItem { Logo = flag, Name = item.Name, Land = item.Land, Region = item.Region});
                }
            }
    
    
    private async Task<Image> LoadFlag(string countrycode, HttpClient client)
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.countryflagsapi.com/png/" + countrycode),
                };
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    Stream imageStreamSource = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                    BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

                    // Draw the Image
                    Image myImage = new Image();
                    myImage.Source = bitmapSource;
                    myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                    myImage.Height = 15;
                    myImage.Width = 15;
                    myImage.Margin = new Thickness(20);

                    pic.Children.Add(myImage);
                    return myImage;
                }
```

XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#505050" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFDADADA" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="mainList" Background="#202020" Margin="20,100,20,10" BorderBrush="#505050" Foreground="#FFDADADA">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Logo" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="565"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Land" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Land}" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Region" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Region}" Width="50"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Canvas x:Name="pic"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind the `Source` property of an `Image` element (in XAML) to another `Image` element (created in code). That won't work.

Do not use the `Image` type in view model code. `Image` is a view element.

Change the type of the `Logo` property and the return type of the to `LoadFlag` method to `ImageSource`.

```
private static async Task<ImageSource> LoadFlag(
    string countrycode, HttpClient client)
{
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(
        $"https://www.countryflagsapi.com/png/{countrycode}");

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
        BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}

...

ImageSource flag = await LoadFlag(item.Land, client);

mainList.Items.Add(new CarListItem { Logo = flag, ... });
```

and bind it like this:

```
<Image Width="15" Height="15" Margin="20" Source="{Binding Logo}"/>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, altough i had some challenge to change the C# Version of the Project to 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the `Source` property of an `Image` element to another `Image` element.

Try this:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Logo}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```